# calculate time with datejs and timejs

Tags: jquery, datejs

I am trying to calculate time with datejs and timejs but I am not getting it.

how can i do this?

```
var startTime ="20:55",
    endTime ="22:33",    
    st = (startTime.toString("HH:mm")),
    et=(endTime.toString("HH:mm"));
console.log(new TimeSpan(et-st));


logged: NaN:NaN:NaN { milliseconds=NaN, days=NaN, hours=NaN
```

Comment: I was thinking you already had a date object - try @floatingLomas answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var startTime = Date.parse("20:55"),
    endTime = Date.parse("22:33");

console.log(new TimeSpan(endTime - startTime));
```

`startTime` and `endTime` are strings, and you want them to be milliseconds.

*EDIT: I initially had `.getTime()` on the end of the `Date.parse()`s, but as geoffrey.mcgill pointed out, it wasn't necessary.*

Comment: you are the man, thank you... and then toString, got it... ty

Comment: You shouldn't require the .getTime() calls. Subtracting the two Date objects will give you the same value.